# Is there any hidden costs for Heroku hosting?

Tags: heroku

Is there any hidden costs for Heroku hosting? is flat rate per hosting **really** flat?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about billing, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The costs are exactly as advertised. I've been using Heroku for a long time, even have a verified account (added a credit card) and have never received a charge.

I got a verified account so I get the monthly 1000 free dyno hours enough to host an app on there 24/7. (A month has ~720 hours.)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification